# Subquery returns more than 1 row - solution for greater than condition

Tags: mysql

I want to know if there is a MySQL solution to this problem:

```
UPDATE table2
SET col2 = (SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE  id >= 10)
WHERE  id2 >= 10;
```

There is an error on MySQL that said:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Or would it be more correct to use PHP?

UPD:

```
UPDATE table2 JOIN table1
ON table2.id2 = table1.id
SET table2.col2 = table1.col1
WHERE table2.id2 > 10;
```

Here is a simple solution to my problem, maybe it will be useful to the same beginners as me.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do, so it's not clear what the right solution is. Can you explain what you are attempting to do here? I'm betting there is a relatively simple solution in mysql so you don't have to bump out to PHP and monkey with arrays and loops.

Comment: Can you post your sample data and structure? And based on your query, the sub query will return multiple values and you are trying to update multiple values in to a single column value which cannot be done. Is that what you are tryng to ?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I'm just trying to copy the values from the first table to the second for all tables with id greater than 10

Comment: Basing on which condition? And what is the relation between table1 and table2?

Comment: This SQL request does not work only with the condition greater or less than ...so I'm trying to figure out how to do the right thing: by means of MySQL or php

Answer (score 0):

You can use "in" 
UPDATE table2 SET col2 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE  id >= 10) WHERE  id2 >= 10;

Comment: I have already tried to use IN, but in another version, but your example is also not very successful.